# bidirectional socat functionality with nc

Tags: netcat, socat

This is question is somehow related to
https://superuser.com/questions/270698/how-is-it-called-when-listeningconnecting-two-sockets-and-exchanging-data-betw

In the test setup I have three terminal windows open
I run in

```
Term1: "nc -l 55545"
Term2: "nc -l 55546"
Term3: "socat tcp:localhost:55545 tcp:localhost:55546"
```

Input to Term1 now appears in Term2 and
input to Term2 appears in Term1.

This is the desired behavior.
How can I achieve this behavior by only
using nc?

When I run in

```
Term3: "nc localhost 55545 | nc localhost 55546"
```

then Input to Term1 appears in Term2 but
input to Term2 appears in Term3.
How can I make the pipe bidirectional?
If possible without temporary files.

Answer (score 14):

This comes straight from the [Wikipedia page on netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Proxying).  In Term3, you would run:

```
mkfifo backpipe
nc localhost 55545 0<backpipe | nc localhost 55546 1>backpipe
```

This does pretty much exactly what you want.  It uses a FIFO to get output from the left-hand side back into the right-hand side.  It's not, strictly speaking, a temporary file -- a FIFO is a named pipe between two processes.

Comment: or do I have that wrong? seems like you need to reference the variable with $ sign and you can leave off the 0 and 1 file descriptors?

Comment: You can of course always use implicit file descriptors. I was just being explicit when I wrote this *7 years ago*. I'm not sure what variable you're referring to; there are no variables in my answer.

Comment: nice that works, I follow